# Is it possible to only scroll an image rather than the entire site without position: sticky?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have a site with a header, a heading and a giant image.

---

**The image is bigger than the site's height**, this is a long coincidence and actually played out pretty nicely in the end effect/idea-wise.

**I want to create a scrolling effect where the user scrolls but only the image "scrolls" / moves**. The lower end of the image becomes visible while the top end disappears exactly what you'd expect from scrolling.

---

### *Here's a sketch of the site's structure and idea:*

[image]

When the user scrolls down the header and anything above it stays the same, no floating, no odd floats or other edits.

---

I really only want to edit the image css/js/html, and want to avoid editing the other elements, both above and below the image.

Is this possible? I have Bootstrap and Jquery installed (XAMPP/LAMP), perhaps there's library for this type of effect?

Update (min. code):

```
<?php ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>...</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="blackbg navbar navbar-expand-lg row">
            <span class="col-1"></span>
            <a class="display-4 navbar_Item col-5" href="#">Item1</a>
            <a class="display-4 navbar_Item col-5" href="#">Item2</a>
            <span class="col-1"></span>
        </nav>
        <section class="spacing10percent"></section>
        <h1 class="display-3 lgtext">Some nice heading</h1>
        <img src="verticalImage.png" />
        <script src="js/jquery.3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
        <footer>
            <small>Privacy Policy</small>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add some minimal code which demonstrates your HTML structure and also describe why position: sticky is not a possibility for this problem?

Comment: @AHaworth added. Because it will create issues down the line when I want to stop the menu from being sticky and vise versa. I also doubt it will help with this issue and might probably create further issues given the great height of the image. (Lastly I really like only editing things to a bare minimum / no cross editing / no giant undo session etc... and now further design/structure issues...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 5: set the img as `background-image`** (toggle max:width: 100% with `fit`)

```js
const fit = false;
let width, height, newHeight;
$(window).on('load', function() {
  const src = $('img').attr('src');
  width = $('img').width();
  height = $('img').height();
  $('img').remove();
  $('<div>', {
    id: 'img',
    css: { 'background-image': `url("${src}")` }
  }).appendTo('body');
  resize();
});

function resize() {
  let css;
  if (!fit) {
    newHeight = height;
    css = {
      'width': width,
      'height': newHeight
    };
  }
  else {
    newHeight = height * Math.min(width, $(window).width()) / width;
    css = {
      'width': width < $(window).width() ? width : '100%',
      'height': newHeight,
      'background-size': '100% auto',
      'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
    };
  }
  $('#img').css(css);
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  const h = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('body').css('padding-top', h);
  $('#img').css('background-position', `0 ${-h}px`);
  $('#img').height(newHeight - h);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  resize();
});
```

```css
#img {
  border: 1px red solid;
  border-top-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>HEADER</header>
<div class="heading"><h1>H1</h1></div>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000">
```

---

**Method 1: Wrap the `img` (preview it in full screen)**

```css
header {
  height: 200px;
}

.heading {
  height: 100px;
}

.img-container {
  height: calc(100% - 300px);
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 95%;
}
```

```html
<header>HEADER</header>
<div class="heading"><h1>H1</h1></div>
<div class="img-container">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000">
</div>
```

---

**Method 2: fix the img container** (background color problem)

```js
$('#img').css('margin-top', $('body').outerHeight(true));
$(window).scroll(function() {
  const st = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('body').css('padding-top', st);
});
```

```css
#img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>HEADER</header>
<div class="heading"><h1>H1</h1></div>
<div id="img">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000">
</div>
```

---

**Method 3: fix the img in container** (background color problem)

```js
const d = $('img').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  const a = $(this).scrollTop();
  const b = $('img').height();
  const c = $(this).height();
  const h = a < b - c + d ? a : b - c + d;
  $('body').css('padding-top', h);
  $('img').css('top', -h);
  $('#img').height(1000 - h);
});
```

```css
#img {
  position:relative;
  z-index:-99;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>HEADER</header>
<div class="heading"><h1>H1</h1></div>
<div id="img">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000">
</div>
```

---

**Method 4: scroll with `object-position`** (white space after img problem)

```js
const d = $('img').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  const a = $(this).scrollTop();
  const b = $('img').height();
  const c = $(this).height();
  const h = a < b - c + d ? a : b - c + d;
  $('body').css('padding-top', h);
  $('img').css('object-position', `0 ${-h}px`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>HEADER</header>
<div class="heading"><h1>H1</h1></div>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000">
```

Comment: good answer but not quite there yet, the image is scrollable  only when the user scrolls the image, not the page which is confusing to anyone who doesn't have the pre-info.

Comment: Then there will be 2 parts i) make header and h1 to move with scroll and ii) make img to move with scroll. Do you accept creating a dummy 'header and h1'?

Comment: Sure I don't know what that means though :).

How do you move the image and and nav/header at the same time while "moving" the image further? 
I'm conficious and confused.
At this point use sticky headers I don't mind because I can't seem to find a solution. I just can't think of a way to move the navbar down, clip onto the h1 (the h1 now moves with the navbar sticky) and not overscroll the img, while scrolling the img scrolls down.

Comment: Added methods 2,3,4. 2 and 3 are similar. There are some problem with each method. Use of 'dummy' header is also the same thing of using header itself, so I gave up this idea.

Comment: Method 4 looks the closest to what I am trying to achieve. You deserve thegreen tick just for the effort alone thanks.

Comment: I added Method 5. It should fulfil your requirements.

Comment: perfect! Thanks